# presence validation is not working when asking (.valid?), but correctly fails on .save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have the following files on my project:

*migration:*

```
create_table :stores do |t|
  t.string :slug, null: false, index: { unique: true }
  t.string :name, null: false, index: { unique: true }
  t.text :description, null: false

  t.timestamps
end
```

*model:*

```
class Store < ApplicationRecord
  validates :slug,
            presence: true,
            uniqueness: true,
            length: { minimum: 2, maximum: 36 },
            allow_blank: false
  validates :name,
            presence: true,
            uniqueness: true,
            length: { minimum: 2, maximum: 64 },
            allow_blank: false
  validates :description,
            presence: true,
            length: { minimum: 0, maximum: 1024 },
            allow_blank: true
end
```

When i run `rails c` and execute the following line of code:

```
Store.new(slug: 'blah', name: 'Blah').valid?
// returns true
```

it returns true, but when I try to save it

```
Store.new(slug: 'blah', name: 'Blah').save
// fails to save, NOT_NULL constraint failed
```

it fails to save, due to `NOT_NULL constraint` failure.

Why isn't `valid?` returning `false`, if there is no `description` field and there's a validation requiring its presence on the model?

---

Ruby Version: 2.7.0
Rails Version: 6.0.2.1

Comment: Your issue is caused by the NOT NULL constraint in your database "null: false" on description column. The "valid?" method does not test the constraints you set in your database. Either remove the constraint from your database, or ensure the description is an empty string (instead of nil).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Jean-MichelGigault. `valid?` should return `false` because I have the following validation on my **model**: `validates :description, presence: true`

Comment: No because you also added "allow_blank: true", allowing nulls and empty string :-)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I did not know 'allow_blank' was used for nil values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your "description" column is throwing this database error. There is a not-null constraint in migration for description whereas in Model validations you have set allow blank.
You can provide a default value(i.e. "") to the description column in migration.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I did not know 'allow_blank' was used for nil values.